# Tips on how to clean my copy of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS？

Tags: software-installation

I want to know how to clean my copy of Ubuntu 16.04. I want to delete all the things that are unnecessary and temporary in my system.

Also, what are the things that I should do after a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation? The installation is good, but I want to implement things that can help clean the system. Are there any good tips on doing so?

Comment: i need how to sign out my account comunity okap?understoods i don't know it where go?! it's a simple thing

Comment: Put your comment in your question by editing the question. Comments are not for posting additional questions. (I just submitted a suggested edit.)

Comment: Humberto, your question is not so clear. I suggest you write it in portuguese at Google Tradutor and post English output at your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need guidance on what next after installing Ubuntu 16.04, this could help

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Cleaning Ubuntu can be done using apps which clear cache ( mostly )

There is Stacer, BleachBit etc

> Linux System Optimizer and Monitoring

https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer

> BleachBit deletes unnecessary files to free valuable disk space,
>   maintain privacy, and remove junk. It removes cache, Internet history,
>   temporary files, cookies, and broken shortcuts.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/bleachbit/